awk command to replace block between two tags with contents of variable
I've seen many variations of this question on stack overflow/exchange, but none of them seem to address exactly what I'm looking for.
I have a file that looks like this:
bla
bla
bla
tag
text 1
text 2
tag
bla
bla

I have a variable (call it X) that contains
alpha
beta
gamma

I'm looking for an awk (or sed) expression that removes the text between the two "tag" lines and replaces it with the contents of variable X.  The end result should be:
bla
bla
bla
tag
alpha
beta
gamma
tag
bla
bla

I think I need to do something like this:
awk -v var="$X" 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n"} /tag/ {print var; next} {print $0"\n"}'

but this deletes the tags and injects two copies of $X

As always with these seemingly simple questions, the devil is in the details. [edit] your question to state your requirements for - both tags on 1 line, nested tags, overlapping tags, just 1 tag present, tags with RE metachars, tags that could be substrings of other  strings in the input, X containing backreference metachars, X containing common delimiters like /, etc...

Here's one approach.
awk -v var="$X" '/tag/ && !p {
    print; print var; p=1; next}
  /tag/ {p=0} !p'

This removes the pesky manipulations of Awk's internal variables, and instead uses a simple state variable p which is true in the range when you don't want to simply print the current line. The first time you see tag, print the variable also, and set p to 1. The next time, turn off p again.
Demo: https://ideone.com/pFvU1B

note that awk interprets escapes,etc in var (consider awk -v var='\nhello\nworld' 'BEGIN{print var}'). To avoid that, you could pass in the enironment (eg. var="$X" awk '... ENVIRON["var"] ...')

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):
x='alpha
beta
gamma'

sed -e '/tag/r /dev/stdin' -e '//,//{//!d}' <<<"$x" file

When a line containing tag is encountered read the file /dev/stdin which is connected to the here-string and contains $x.
When a range between two tag's is encountered delete all lines except those containing tag.
N.B. The one-liner is split into two parts as the r command demands to be terminated by a newline. The -e option provides the said newline. Also once the file /dev/stdin has been read it is depleted and a second read has no effect. Finally when a match // contains no regexp the last regexp is used in its place.

/tag/r /dev/stdin ... <<<"$x" nice!

Warning this solution assumes that number of tag lines is always evenly divisible by 2, if you can not provide that ignore this answer entirely.
I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
bla
bla
bla
tag
text 1
text 2
tag
bla
bla

then
X=$(echo -e "alpha\nbeta\ngamma")
awk -v var="$X" 'BEGIN{RS="(^tag\n)|(\ntag\n)"}{printf "%s%s",NR%2?$0:var,RT}' file.txt

gives output
bla
bla
bla
tag
alpha
beta
gamma
tag
bla
bla

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that RS is start of string followed by tag followed by newline (this is case if tag is in 1st line) or tag encased in newlines or in others words tag spanning whole line. I use printf to output string followed by row terminator (RT). Note that as I use tag lines as row separator we are inside tag if number of line is even. Therefore I use so-called ternary operator (condition?valueiftrue:valueiffalse) which does provide line as-is if number of row is odd (i.e. where there is some non-zero remainder after division by 2) and content of variable var if number of row is not odd.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
